# psd of an ac voltage signal

Tags: fft, power-spectral-density

In an lab class experiment who's subject of interest was Johnson's noise I measured the ac voltage of a battery. Now I wish to find the psd of the measurement and show that it is constant.

1.Is such a thing even possible with 255 ac measurements in a $0.043s$ spacing?

2. How can it be done without a direct measurement of the voltage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute the PSD, you'd need full amplitude/phase measurements of the noise signal.

If by "255 ac measurements", you mean measurements of the RMS amplitude by a [digital multimeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimeter), then you do not have the necessary phase information.

If by "255 ac measurements", you mean you are using an oscilloscope that is [AC coupled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitive_coupling), then you can consider the measurements to be a measurement of the voltage with the average value ("DC component") removed.   If we consider the voltage signal to be
$$
v_\text{total}(t) = v_\text{DC} + v_\text{AC}(t),
$$
$v_\text{DC}$ is going to be nearly entirely the "normal" contribution of the battery, and constant with time, and $v_\text{AC}(t)$ is going to vary with time and due entirely to thermal noise.  If your measurement is measuring $v_\text{AC}(t)$, then that is what you want anyways.

Once you have waveform samples, the PSD can be estimated using the [periodogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodogram) (easiest, but noisy) or a more advanced method like [Welch's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_method) or [Blackman-Tukey method](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/earth-atmospheric-and-planetary-sciences/12-864-inference-from-data-and-models-spring-2005/lecture-notes/tsamsfmt_1_12.pdf).

Comment: Yes, even if the phase is only 0$^\circ$ or $\pm$180$^\circ$ (real signal)

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz You seem to be missing the basic point that if you have amplitudes and a sign (plus or minus), that is what constitutes a time series.

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz If you have a technical point to make, please post it as an answer. Comments are not for debates: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: I did make a technical point. Full measurement amplitude and phase, in the context of Johnson Noise? Define it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77435/discussion-between-carlos-danger-and-stanley-pawlukiewicz).

Comment: I’ve explained my objection. You can either edit your answer or ignore me. I’ve said what I need to. I have 40 years of being employed in Signal Processing. Words have meaning and yours could use some elaboration, which you don’t seem to agree with.  So....